# isFunction() always false in jQuery

Tags: jquery

so I'm using qtip for a super simple tool tip implementation.

I'm not including qtip on every page, only the pages that needed, so I'm trying to check for qtip's existence before calling it.

```
 /*
  * Tool Tip
  * inits qtip on any link with class="tt"
  */
  if( $.isFunction( $.qtip ) ){
  $(".tt").qtip();
  }
```

I've no idea what this isn't working. it's always returning false. Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMO, you should check

```
if($.isFunction($.fn.qtip))
```

Comment: Just ran in to the same "d'oh" moment. Thanks for posting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if( $.isFunction( $.fn.qtip ) ){
    $(".tt").qtip();
}
```

as plugins reside in the `$.fn` object

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the typof operator since it's not jQuery dependent.

```
if(typeof window.myFunction == 'function') {
    // function exists, so we can now call it
    myFunction();
}
```

On a side note it's a great way to "extend" javascript on "If" something exists (like form validation)

Comment: Since the qtip function is itself dependent on jQuery, I've no issues using isFunction.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation is consistent accross all you your pages, then just put

```
$(function(){
    $(".tt").qtip();
}
```

at the bottom of the qtip.js file, that way, it is executed whenever qtip is included.

Comment: on second thoughts this is probably a bad plan, could be very confusing 6 months down the line!

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $.isFunction(qtip) ){
 //bla bla
}
```

try this or with commas

```
if( $.isFunction("qtip") ){
     //bla bla
    }
```

Comment: won't work, because the `qtip` resides in jQuery fn object -> `jQuery.fn`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "$." before the qtip in the isFunction check.

Comment: `qtip` is a jquery plugin, so he cannot remove jquery dollar sign `$`